# required field validator does not work in Django on azure

Tags: python, django, azure

I have a simple registration form. Where people can fill the information and when they submit the form, data should come in the DB.

The application is working fine in my localhost. I have some required field in my form. When I run the application on my localhost and I try to submit form without filling required field then it shows a pop-up and says that ** The field can't be empty ** , but when I deploy it on my azure portal and try to save this without filling required field then it generates the error:

```
 ValueError at /register/
 The UserInformation could not be created because the data didn't validate.
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://pythonfabric.azurewebsites.net/register/
 Django Version:    1.9.4
 Exception Type:    ValueError
 Exception Value:    
 The UserInformation could not be created because the data didn't validate.
 Exception Location:    D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-      packages\django\forms\models.py in save, line 446
 Python Executable: D:\Python27\python.exe
 Python Version:    2.7.8
 Python Path:    
 [u'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\env\\Lib\\site-packages',
  '.',
 'D:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'D:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Python27\\lib',
 'D:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'D:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'D:\\Python27',
 'D:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot']
  Server time:  Thu, 9 Feb 2017 19:17:07 +0000
```

**register.html**

```
 from django import forms
 from django.forms import ModelForm
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from app.models import UserInformation
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


 class UserInformationForm(ModelForm):
    firstName = forms.CharField(max_length=254, 
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))
    lastName = forms.CharField(
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))
    emailAddress = forms.EmailField(
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))
    phoneNumber = forms.CharField( required=False,
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))
    orchidNumber = forms.CharField( required=False,
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))

    institution = forms.ChoiceField( choices = [("Inst1","Inst1"), ("Inst2","Inst2"),("Other","Other")]
                                 ,widget=forms.Select({                                   
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))                                    


    otherInstitute = forms.CharField( required=False,
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))
    cstaPI = forms.CharField(
                           widget=forms.TextInput({
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               }))

     class Meta:
         model = UserInformation
         exclude = ()
```

**views.py**

```
 @csrf_protect
 def register(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UserInformationForm(request.POST)
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
     else:
         form = UserInformationForm()
         variables =  { 'form': form }

     return render(request, 'registration/register.html',variables)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called `is_valid` anywhere. It should be:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = UserInformationForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
```

Comment: I did it earlier , but then it throws error: local variable 'variables' referenced before assignment on line return render(request, 'registration/register.html',variables)

Comment: You need to move the definition of `variables` back one indent.

Comment: Ok , great its working Thank you, but how required field will work, which is my actual problem in this post